# Huawei Toolkit can not analyze my project

Tags: android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to use Huawei Toolkit to understand my google dependencies in my project and add huawei services. However, every time, when I want to analyze the whole project and start new conversion, analysis does not complete and get an error like this "failed to execute the engine analysis task".

Android studio version is 3.6.2 and I am on windows 10 and toolkit version is 2.0.3.301.

Error is like at image:

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Please provide more details such as the HMS Core Toolkit version you used, the IDE version, your operation system, the record of error logs... and then continue error analysis.

Comment: i added version numbers and error image, only i have these @shirley

Comment: @mika If you are on windows 10, you can find your record of error logs here: C:\Users\{UserName}\.hmstoolkit\logs. Please add these in your question.

Comment: Do you solve this? Plz add the record of error logs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and in your case it might also be related to the use of Kotlin. The Converter of the Toolkit does only support basic Kotlin syntax so that some projects written in Kotlin might run into this issue.

This does not mean there is no alternative because for of the most frequent kits like [Push](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/push-conversion-0000001050060304), [Analytics](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/analytics-conversion-0000001050060148), [Location](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/location-conversion-0000001050062209), and more, manual conversion guides exist.